# From where will I get vertically partitioned dataset for mining association rules?

Tags: dataset, associations, data-mining, rule, database-partitioning

I am working on project privacy preserving data mining for association rules, for that I require sample vertically partitioned binary data set. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge all datasets that are available for association rule mining on the web (e.g. the FIMI 03 and FIMI 04 website) are in horizontal format.  I would suggest to write a simple program to convert a public dataset from horizontal to vertical format.  You can get datasets for association rule mining on the FIMI website: http://fimi.ua.ac.be/data/